# Конфликт правил iptables, использующих ipset

Tags: linux, ip, iptables, ipset

Есть два одинаковых правила для цепочки INPUT, разрешающих входящие запросы от ip, перечисленных в ipset и запрещающих от всех остальных ip. Только в первом правиле список set1,а во втором set2.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m set —set set1 src -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m set —set set2 src -j ACCEPT
```

set1 и set2 - разные списки.Что будет с ip-адресами, перечисленными в set1, будут ли они заблокированы вторым правилом?  И если set1 и set2 имеют повторяющиеся ip-адреса, можно ли объединить списки с повторяющимися ip-адресами в одном правиле и как это сделать?

Comment: Вы бы сами правила привели, по описанию ничего не понятно

Comment: Привел правила в вопросе

Comment: iptables очень просто обрабатывает список правил, а именно в вашем случае либо только первый набор будет разрешающим, либо оба — всё зависит от той части, которую вы не привели.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведенном примере списки сложились. Они ничего не запрещают. Если ip попал в set1, то он обработается в первом правиле и во второе не попадет. Если не попал в set1, по проверяется в set2 и если он попал в set2, то дальнейшие правила не обрабатываются - уходит в ACCEPT.

Объединять списки смысла нет если они не пересекаются или пересекаются не сильно. Стоит их объединить если большая часть трафика не попадает в эти списки - тоесть трафика на правилах за ними больше чем на них. Смотрите счётчики